# Facebook Pixel + WooCommerce + AJAX = Confusion

Tags: ajax, woocommerce-offtopic, facebook

I am trying to add a Facebook Pixel (tracking) to the WooCommerce **Add to Cart** button, using:

```
<script>
 fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
</script>
```

The problem is that when a user clicks on **Add to Cart**, he is not directed to another page on which I could put the pixel, but rather the cart is updated via AJAX.

The WooCommerce form code is as follows:

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php
 echo sprintf( '<button type="submit" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="1" class="%s button product_type_simple">%s</button>', esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) );
?>
</form>
```

If I had the `<img>` code, I'm sure I could load it via **onClick**, but I'm not sure how to add `fbq('track', 'AddToCart');` to the **Add to Cart** button.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Maybe load the Pixel via jQuery? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi there flomei, I've updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I think [`.bind()`](https://api.jquery.com/bind/) and/or [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) might come in handy here. You could possibly attach the tracking function to the click-event for your "Add to Cart"-button.

But I´m no JavaScript/jQuery guy, so someone else has to help you here.